# Does RSA encryption affect export compliance?

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, app-store-connect

I am using https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA this library to encrypt some data using a public key.

Current live app is already using **https** for all calls. I am confused as to **how** will my answers on **export compliance** change on version update?

Also, do I need to add export compliance documentation on itunes connect?

Additional details:

1. I am using **only** encryption from the library.
2. Then the encrypted string is sent to server. The backend server is responsible for decryption using private key.
3. The encryption is **NOT** for authentication purpose. It is used send sensitive data to server

Comment: why are you encrypting your data when you already are using https? Why are you going through the trouble of explicitly en/decrypting data and not let the network layers do all the work for you as they already do?

Comment: It is a requirement of the (back-end)APIs I am using.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my use case was falling under the **money transactions** category. As per the export guidelines, this category is allowed to use cryptographic algos.
All I had to do is mark "Yes" to the below questions during submission.

As per [FAQ on iTunes Connect](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Trade%20Compliance#56254694):

> Does your product qualify for any exemptions provided under category 5 part 2?
>
> (v) your app is specially designed and limited for banking use or ‘money transactions.’ The term ‘money transactions’ includes the collection and settlement of fares or credit functions.